# Google Reader API: Continuation for stream/items/ids

Tags: google-reader

Is there any way to get `continuation` for `/api/0/stream/items/ids` like `/api/0/stream/contents/`?

If no, how can I get next item-ids of a stream? Or is there any way to convert item-id/timestamp to continuation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/api/0/stream/items/ids` endpoint supports an `nt` parameter that you can use to get increasingly older items. You can take the timestamp (in microseconds) of the oldest item that you already have, convert it to seconds, and then pass it in as a the `ot` parameter. See [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/ApiStreamItemsIds) for the full list of parameters that are supported.

Comment: Oh thanks! I don't remember correctly but I think I had read somewhere that using nt/ot is limited to around 1 or few months ago. So I just didn't try them before asking! Instead I waste a day trying to decode continuation!

Comment: Mihai, would you please have a look at my other google reader question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733926