# Google Reader API: Unauthorized Search?

Tags: google-reader

Is there any way to search on a stream/feed for an item without authentication? `/reader/api/0/search/items/ids` returns Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The primary use-case for search is to search over items the user has read in feeds they're subscribed to.